# How to put the timer at the top of the screen?

Tags: ipad, clock

I am looking to show the timer going down (not the clock symbol) at the top of my screen (somewhere in the space in red).

[image]

I do not know if this is possible, but if it is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with public API. It's only available on iPhones with dynamic island.

In order to do something like this, Jailbreak might be needed.